# crystal report is displaying blank screen in Internet explorer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, crystal-reports

asp.net mvc crystal report is displaying blank screen in Internet explorer 10.But the same report is working properly in chrome and firefox. Can anyone give a suggestion?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check the compatibility mode settings? Not sure if its related to the problem but worth checking.

Comment: thank you. i changed the document mode to IE7 standards. Now it is working. But how to make it work in IE10 standards?

Comment: I havent used CR for a while, so that's really tough to tell; but you can try specifying `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"/>` meta tag on your page which will run the report in compatibility mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you nilesh. That solved the issue.
In the crystal report viewer we have to add the following code:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9,chrome=1" />
```

The following is an example.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ReportViewer.aspx.cs" Inherits="Project1.Web.ReportViewer.ReportViewer" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"
Namespace="CrystalDecisions.Web" TagPrefix="CR" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"/>


<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1" runat="server" 
        AutoDataBind="True" GroupTreeImagesFolderUrl="" Height="50px" 
        ReportSourceID="CrystalReportSource1" ToolbarImagesFolderUrl="" 
        ToolPanelWidth="200px" Width="350px" PrintMode="ActiveX" />
    <CR:CrystalReportSource ID="CrystalReportSource1" runat="server">
        <Report FileName="~/Reports/Report1.rpt">
        </Report>
    </CR:CrystalReportSource>

</div>
</form>
```

Comment: May I know this line of code need to put into which file?

Comment: I am doing with master page, so the <meta...> need to put in master page or the viewer page?

Answer (score 1):

This fixed it for me. What it neglects to mention is the crystalReportViewer folder has to be copied from Program Files(x86) to the proper subfolder under aspnet_client. You may already have a  block in web.config. You only need one. The second bit of code goes below that section.

```
Copy the folders under "\inetpub\wwwroot\aspnet_client\" and paste them under the  root of the custom web site

 Add the following to the application web.config file:

<configSections>

    <sectionGroup name="businessObjects">
      <sectionGroup name="crystalReports">
        <section name="crystalReportViewer" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler"/>
      </sectionGroup>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <businessObjects>
    <crystalReports>
      <crystalReportViewer>
        <add key="UseBrowserLocale" value="true"/>
        <add key="resourceURI" value="~/aspnet_client/system_web/4_0_30319/crystalreportviewers13" />
      </crystalReportViewer>
    </crystalReports>
  </businessObjects>
```

Be sure that the name for the folder crystalreportviewers in web.config matches the name in aspnet_client.