# Crystal report with IE11

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-11, silverlight-5.0, crystal-reports-2010

I have a silverlight 4 application and i upgrade to silverlight 5 and i use crystal report to show and print reports but after upgrading the reports appears as blank (empty) in interne explorer 11 
Is it possible to open crystal report in IE11 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be compatibility issue or ActiveX control issue. You could try the following methods:

- Please add the site of crystal report into [IE compatibility view](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17472/windows-internet-explorer-11-fix-site-display-problems-compatibility-v#ie=ie-11) to have a try.
- Please make sure [ActiveX filtering is not turned on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgy8M.png). Open Internet Explorer and select the **Tools** button. Make sure there's no tick before **ActiveX Filtering**.
- You could try to add the following meta tag to make it compatible with IE 11:

  `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9,chrome=1" />`

For more information, you could refer to [this thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/1da0a049-8514-4274-a70f-1cf2f127c4bf/crystal-report-viewer-do-not-show-in-internet-explorer-11?forum=ieitprocurrentver) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18529805/crystal-report-is-displaying-blank-screen-in-internet-explorer).

Comment: But i have another problem after that upgrade: the tag TimeUpDown doesn't exist in namespace toolkit what can i do

Comment: You're welcome. I'll try to have a look and to see if I can solve the problem.